# DLLimport using and Error

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper

I have a c++ native dll file and I should call some functions from Dll by c#

the c++ function that I should call is

`extern NCSError NCS_CALL NCSOpenFileViewA(const char *szUrlPath, NCSFileView **ppNCSFileView,NCSReadStatus (*pRefreshCallback)(NCSFileView *pNCSFileView));`

NCSFileView object is

```
typedef struct NCSFileViewStruct NCSFileView;
```

and working example c++ code is

```
NCS::CApplication App
NCSCompressClient *pClient;
char *szInputFilename = "C:\\testdata\\RGB_8bit.ecw";
NCSFileView *pNCSFileView;
NCSFileInfo *pNCSFileInfo;
NCSFileMetaData *pNCSFileMeta;
NCSError eError;
NCSInit();
eError = NCSOpenFileViewA(szInputFilename, &pNCSFileView, NULL);
if (eError != NCS_SUCCESS) {
    ReportError("Could not open view for file:%s, Error = %s",
        szInputFilename, NCSGetErrorText(eError));
    exit(1);
}`
```

I made a c# code like this

```
[DllImport("C:\\NCSEcw.dll",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr NCSOpenFileViewA ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string path, 
IntPtr a, 
IntPtr c);
```

but i get en error like this

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

so, can you help me to write wrapper?

Comment: Why use `IntPtr` for `NCSError`? You can use `out`, instead of `IntPtr` for single pointer. Use `out IntPtr` for double pointer. (ppNCSFileView). How did you call it to produce the error?

Comment: I have not tried someting like importing dll. So I just made a try.. I dont know what should I do, I just try things... @mutex36

Comment: I don't understand. You tried what?

Comment: I just want to call    extern NCSError NCS_CALL NCSOpenFileViewA(const char *szUrlPath, NCSFileView **ppNCSFileView,NCSReadStatus (*pRefreshCallback)(NCSFileView *pNCSFileView));   function from c#

Comment: It worked by out keyword. Thank you friend. Sorry for my bad english :-)